# Can a list item animation be achieved with a single div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am currently trying to achieve an animated look for list items like seen in Pasquale D’Silva's example: https://medium.com/design-ux/926eb80d64e3#1f47

The list item disappears and the empty space seems to retain it's height for a split second before collapsing to 0 height.

The way I've achieved this is by having a div with a transparent background and have another div within that one that holds the actual content.

I'll animate the inner div, pause for a little bit and then set the height of the outer div to 0.

This is my attempt on codepen: http://codepen.io/michaellee/pen/Cnpcf (Click on an item  to make it disappear.)

I'm wondering if the same effect could be achieved without having a div within a div?

**HTML**

```
<div class="stackOne">
    <div class="item-holder">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-holder">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-holder">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-holder">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-holder">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.stackOne{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  .item-holder{
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    .item{
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      background: #ccc;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.stackOne .item').click(function(){
  var item = $(this);
  item.animate({
    left: "100%"
  }, 250, "swing", function() {
    item.parent().delay(100).animate({
      height: 0
    }, 50, "linear", function(){
      item.parent().hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? Is it more suitable for http://ux.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @zfus I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: @zfus My guess is that it comes off as opinion based? Just a guess though, to me this seems perfectly acceptable... Maybe try including the code in the post and rephrasing so it doesn't ask if there's a "better way."

Comment: You haven't described what's wrong with what you already have.  Right now it just looks like you have a working solution that you're trying to micro-optimize (which isn't what SO is for).

Comment: @DrydenLong Thanks will try to rephrase.

Comment: @cimmanon Gotcha. Will update question.

Comment: @cimmanon - that makes sense. Thank you. I feel that it is more valuable to point out an improvement through a comment than a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the container and apply your animations directly to the child - new JS:

```
$('.stackOne .item').click(function(){
  var item = $(this);
  item.animate({
    left: "100%"
  }, 250, "swing", function() {
    item.delay(100).animate({
      height: 0
    }, 150, "linear", function(){
      item.hide();
    });
  });
});
```

[New CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ECsbF)